# Google Translate for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-translate

I have a lot of dynamic pages in German.I want to translate them to English. After translation, i have to insert them to database. Are there any plugins that uses Google's Language API ? Thanks

Comment: What's the point? If I want to read a horribly translated version of your site then I'll just type its URL into translate.google.com myself.

Comment: The point was clear. He would like to store the translation after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it, but it looks like Google themselves have a [Rails bridge](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/gdata_on_rails.html) into their [Data APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html), which includes the [Google Translator Toolkit](http://code.google.com/apis/gtt/).

Comment: It says the translator API is restricted now .